# MongoDB Function not returning array correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am attempting to find out if each string in an array exists on MongoDB in a simple and efficient way. The field to be searched is known (i.e. name)

The issue that I am running into is that when calling the below function it returns undefined.

```
const generateNaughtyList = (listtoCheck: Array<string>): Array<string> => {
  let doesntExist = []
  listtoCheck.forEach(async (e) => {
    const docCount = await Article.countDocuments({ name: e }).exec();
    if (docCount != 1) doesntExist.push(e)
  })
  return doesntExist
}
```

calling function

```
  const hello = await generateNaughtyList(Stringlist)
  console.log(hello)
```

If I try to console.log out during the loop (i.e.)

```
 if (docCount != 1) console.log('It doesn't exist')
```

It works fine?

If I use another loop method

```
  for (let i = 0; i <= listtoCheck.length-1; i++) {
    const docCount: number = await Article.countDocuments({ name: listtoCheck[i] }).exec();
    if (docCount != 1) doesntExist.push(listtoCheck[i])
  }
```

It works fine. The forEach doesn't seem to want to work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Sorry I missed the await out in the original post (it was called as an async function). It doesn't however solve the problem.

I will update the question with more information

Comment: Since you are using an asynchronous function (Promise) in your `generateNaughtyList` (inside the `listtoCheck.forEach` and inside that callback with `Article.countDocuments({ name: e }).exec()`), JavaScript doesn't wait for all of those Promises to finish, so when you `return doesntExist`, the only thing that has happen so far is: 1) the creation of `doesntExist` variable and 2) All of the `Article.countDocuments` Promises have been started. You would need to convert `generateNaughtyList` to be an async function (returning type `Promise<Array<string>>`) and await that for `const hello = ...`

Comment: And you would also need to use `Promise.all` or something similar to wait for all those MongoDB `Article.countDocuments` Promises to resolve. That's what the answer I linked to says to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current function isn't working because it returns synchronously and modifies the array later.

Change your function to be an `async` function, so that it will resolve *after* it checks all the strings.

In the modified function below, I also used [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in combination to `Array.map()` (instaed of `forEach`) to get an array of results.

```
const generateNaughtyList = async (listtoCheck: Array<string>): Array<string> => 
  await Promise.all(listtoCheck.map(async (e) => {
    const docCount = await Article.countDocuments({ name: e }).exec();
    if (docCount != 1) return e
  }))
```